# How to read till end of file in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, file-io

I have a file `a.txt`:

```
03,17.406199
05,14.580129
07,13.904058
11,14.685388
15,14.062603
20,14.364573
25,18.035175
30,21.681789
50,22.662820
```

The number of rows in the file are not known. I want to read the file and store

```
3
5
7
11
15
20
30
50
```

in one array and the float values in another.

**How do I read in a file when the length of data is not known?**

Comment: Matlab Help is your best friend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the number of entries is the same in every row, and if all the entries are numeric, then
you can simply do

```
a = load('a.txt');
```

`a` will be a matrix with two columns.

Answer (score 4):

Read line-by-line [until you hit the EOF marker](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/import_export/f5-35378.html).

Answer (score 1):

Certain functions (like [TEXTSCAN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html)) will continue recycling the format string until the end of the file is reached. Other functions (like [FSCANF](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fscanf.html)) can take `Inf` as a size option, indicating that it should continue reading until the end of the file. If you are reading data line-by-line in a loop, you can use the [FEOF](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/feof.html) function to test if the end of the file has been reached.

Answer (score 0):

Since your elements are separated by commas, take a look at [csvread](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/csvread.html). This should read the entire file into a single matrix, which you can then split into the two vectors you want.

Disclaimer: not tested!

```
fileContents = csvread('a.txt');
integerColumn = fileContents(:, 1);
doubleColumn = fileContents(:, 2);
```